# C# kill all processes started with Application.Run when main form closes

Tags: c#, winforms, sta

I am starting a bunch of invisible forms in seperate threads from my initial form with

```
 Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
                    {
                        var form= new myform();
                        try
                        {
                            System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(form);
                        }
                        catch (Exception e2) { MessageBox.Show(e.ToString()); }

                    });
                    thread.ApartmentState = ApartmentState.STA;
                    thread.Start();
```

When I close main for, the other threads live on, I have to use

```
taskkill /f /im "myexe.exe"
```

from windows run.

How can I close them all cleanly from my C# form?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Well...you can run that command in a System.Diagnostics.Process

Comment: Add `thread.IsBackground = true;` to make it automagic.

Comment: THANK YOU, now is there a way to kill all the children without exiting the main form?

Comment: Killing children will make you end up in jail.  You have to ask nicely, google "c# cancel a thread".  You also have to review [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dsui_team/2012/10/31/debugging-windows-forms-application-hangs-during-systemevents-userpreferencechanged/), it shows what you have to do when using forms on multiple threads turned out to be a bad idea.

Comment: Yea well I had no alternative, I already had thousands of lines of code relying on the assumption that I was going to be using different forms in different threads

Answer (score 0):

You could keep a reference to each background thread you create, then when you close your main form, just abort all the child threads. Probably not the cleanest solution, but it will work. A better solution would be to send a message to each thread and ask them politely to stop what they're doing, then wait on your main thread until all child threads are finished.

Keep a list of your background threads

```
private List<Thread> myForms = new List<Thread>();
```

In your contructor where you create your background forms, add those threads to this list

```
Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
{
    var form = new Form1();
    try
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(form);
    }
    catch (Exception e2)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e2.ToString());
    }
});

thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
thread.Start();

myForms.Add(thread);
myForms.Add(thread2);
myForms.Add(thread3);
```

Here when we close our main form, you can kill the other threads

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var t in this.threads)
    {
        try
        {
            t.Abort();
        }
        catch (ThreadAbortException)
        {
            // This will happen on each child thread
        }
    }
}
```